# EhCache - Expired elements won't evict

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-cache

I'm using EHCache 2.9 in my Spring Boot application and I've configured the cache to expire after 300 seconds (5 minutes).

When I run the application and request the element for the first time it gets cached and after that never expires. 
However, when I do `@CachePut` it gets updated successfully and updated element is then returned.
What is wrong in my configuration?

Here is my **ehcache.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="false"
                  overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />

    <diskStore path="java.io.tempdir"/>

    <cache name="appointments"
           maxElementsInMemory="5000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="0"
           timeToLiveSeconds="300"
           overflowToDisk="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" />

</ehcache>
```

And here is how I request the cache:

```
@Cacheable("appointments")
public List<Event> getEvents(String eventsForUser, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws Exception {

    return fetchEventsFromTheServer(eventsForUser, startDate, endDate);
}

@CachePut("appointments")
public List<Event> refreshEventsCache(String eventsForUser, Date startDate, Date endDate) throws Exception {

    return fetchEventsFromTheServer(eventsForUser, startDate, endDate);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which Spring Boot version are you using and how have you configured ehcache?

Comment: Spring boot is 1.3.5, I added @EnableCaching annotation to my Application.java and added ehcache.xml to configure it

Comment: Is `ehcache.xml` in the root of the classpath? i.e in `src/main/resources`? If not you need to set the `spring.cache.ehcache.config` property and point it to `ehcache.xml`. Also you might want to remove the specific version tag for ehcache and let spring boot manage the version (then you will get 2.10) .

Comment: I removed ehCache version, so it is 2.10 now, as you said, ehcache.xml file is in the root of the class path, still the same result

Comment: Have you enabled debugging for spring cache and ehcahce? Just to check what is going on?

Comment: can you add cacheManager configuration?

Comment: I have this exact problem. did you ever find a solution?! maybe you could share it back here.

Comment: It turned out for me that ehcache wasn't properly connected. After making sure ehcache.xml is included in the artifact in the right place it started to work for me :) Also make sure you have 'eternal="false"' in cache settings

Answer (score -1):

**Flush** – To move a cache entry to a lower tier. Flushing is used to free up resources while still keeping data in the cluster. Entry E1 is shown to be flushed from the L1 off-heap store to the Terracotta Server Array (TSA).

**Fault** – To copy a cache entry from a lower tier to a higher tier. Faulting occurs when data is required at a higher tier but is not resident there. The entry is not deleted from the lower tiers after being faulted. Entry E2 is shown to be faulted from the TSA to L1 heap.

**Eviction** – To remove a cache entry from the cluster. The entry is deleted; it can only be reloaded from a source outside the cluster. Entries are evicted to free up resources. Entry E3, which exists only on the L2 disk, is shown to be evicted from the cluster.

****Expiration** – A status based on Time To Live and Time To Idle settings. To maintain cache performance, expired entries may not be immediately flushed or evicted. Entry E4 is shown to be expired but still in the L1 heap.**

**Pinning** – To force data to remain in certain tiers. Pinning can be set on individual entries or an entire cache, and must be used with caution to avoid exhausting a resource such as heap. E5 is shown pinned to L1 heap.

http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.7/configuration/data-life.html

Comment: Managing data life in 2.9 version of ehcache, https://www.ehcache.org/generated/2.9.0/html/ehc-all/#page/Ehcache_Documentation_Set%2Fto-life_managing_data_life.html%23